# How to use variable vscode in Developer tools?

Tags: visual-studio-code

Is there any way to use variable vscode to get editor content just like Atom without writing Extension.

After getting editor content, I can do more things like:

1. Use Javascript to modify text literally
2. Custom format

[vscode image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FEQug.png)

[atom image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SGbOR.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. This is not supported.

You can use the [extension API](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/extensions/overview) to extend VS Code. This API lets you get and modify editor contents

Comment: Thx, that's to say I have to write an extension to do this. The only thing what the Developer Tools do is just output the log?